# Bind TextBlock to data or just set the text

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am implementing a real time system that needs to update many TextBlocks multiple times a second.  Specifically I need to update TextBlock.Text and TextBlock.Foreground.

In general is it better (faster and more efficient) to bind the TextBlock.Text and TextBlock.Foreground properties to data or is it more efficient to just dispatch to the UI thread and set these properties manually?

Comment: There's no such thing as `TextBlock.Color`. And use DataBinding. Always. No matter what.

Comment: Just use a profiler to find out...

Comment: I Edited the question.  I meant TextBlock.Foreground.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a converter for your need to change the foreground color of your TextBlock. Here is what the converter class could look like where based on some text we change the color.

```
public class ForegroundColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string sValue = (string)value;
        SolidColorBrush pBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        if (sValue.ToLower() == "red") pBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        return pBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You will need to add a resource to your usercontrol or page.

```
<Page.Resources>
   <local:ForegroundColorConverter x:Name="ColorConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Your texblock will look something like this.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblText" Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding TextColorName, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
```

Almost forgot the class you'll be binding to.

```
public class TextBlockInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //member variables
    private string m_sText = "";
    private string m_sTextColorName = "";

    //construction
    public TextBlockInfo() { }
    public TextBlockInfo(string sText, string sTextColorName)
    {
        m_sText = sText;
        m_sTextColorName = sTextColorName;
    }

    //events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //properties
    public string Text { get { return m_sText; } set { m_sText = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Text"); } }
    public string TextColorName { get { return m_sTextColorName; } set { m_sTextColorName = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TextColorName"); } }

    //methods
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string sName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null) this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(sName));
    }
}
```